# ここんとこ (ここん所) and other "every now and then" adverbs

Tags: formal-nouns, contractions, adverbs, time

I have been in the market for some good synonyms for `ときどき`, and I encountered one today that I wanted to share, and also ask for some opinions, since I can not find a correct definition online.  The specific use I encountered is:

> 俺実は**ここんとこ**ずっと同じ夢を見るの subtitle: "Lately I keep having the same dream"

Context:
http://www.crunchyroll.com/a-dark-rabbit-has-seven-lives/episode-1-900-seconds-of-after-school-part-one-580756 (4 minute 6 second mark)

The entry in the Jim Breen dictionary is:

> 此処ん所; ここん所 【とこ】 (n) this place; here

And I think this is wrong, I think it is of the same general variety as `ときどき`, `ときに`, and `たまに`.  However, I think it probably has a bit of a different nuance as well.  I think that the use here, as well as uses I find in Googling for it, are showing that `ここんとこ` is good for showing that a phenomena has started happening and is currently still happening on and off.  I should qualify that observation by noting that I just totally made that up myself.  I also see some uses that might be referring to something physical, simply as a replacement for `このところ`, but I'm not entirely sure.  Oh, and `ここんところ` seems to substitute without any real difference in meaning.

Obviously I want to ask if anyone can give a definition with confidence.  I would also like to know how this word would fit into your arsenal of words to express occasional occurrences, which is something I'm always wanting more precise words for.  If I had to express the idea in my example I might have said `最近ときどき`, which sounds kind of clumsy now.

Thanks in advance!  I'm new here, and I'll be taking a stop by meta soon to ask some more questions about how to use Japanese SE effectively.

Comment: "Lately" does not mean the same thing as "every now and then".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a contracted form of `ここの所`. `所` typically means place, but has other uses such as heading a relative clause or, as in this case, refering to a time instead of a place. `ここ` is also referring to recent times rather than nearby places. The translation is 'these days', 'recently'. You are right that the dictionary you cited is wrong. It is misinterpreting `所`. The reason it cannot mean 'here' is because that would make the expression redundant. `ここ` already means place, and adding an extra construct would not be motivated unless it changes the meaning.

Interestingly, `そこの所` or `そこん所` also departs from meaning a place. In this case, it means 'what was just mentioned'.

Comment: It is interesting that ここのところ rarely refers to a physical place despite the fact that the primary meanings of ここ (here) and ところ (place) have everything to do with places.